# How calculate the De Rham cohomology group of $3$-torus: $T^3$?

Tags: differential-topology, homology-cohomology

How do I calculate the De Rham cohomology group of the $3$-torus $T^3$? Here $T^3=S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1 $.

Using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, I can show that $\dim H_3(T^3)=\dim H_0(T^3)=1$. But I don't know how to find $H_1(T^3)$ and $H_2(T^3)$.

Comment: Have you seen the Kunneth formula?

Comment: Do you already know the answer for $T^2$?

Comment: I think this is better if you know Kunneth formula...

Comment: Yeah, Jason DeVito

Comment: Mayer-Vietoris and induction can show the dimension of $H^k(T^n)$ is at most $\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}$.  Wedging together the various 1-forms from the $S^1$ components shows it is at least $\binom{n}{k}$.  So you have the dimension is exactly $\binom{n}{k}$, and you know what the generators look like.

Comment: @SteveD: What cover do you use for the Mayer-Vietoris sequence? When I use the obvious choice of splitting $T^n=T^{n-1}\times S^1$ along the $S^1$ I seem to get a Mayer-Vietoris sequence in which all the $T^{n-1}$ terms drop out...

Comment: @spitespike: The cover to use is where $A$ and $B$ are both homotopy equivalent to an $(n-1)$=torus, and also their intersection is homotopy equivalent to an $(n-1)$-torus.  Then the relevant part of Mayer-Vietoris is $H^{k-1}(A\cap B)\rightarrow H^k(X)\rightarrow H^k(A)\oplus H^k(B)\rightarrow H^k(A\cap B)$.

Comment: @SteveD. Thanks. I was considering only dimensions of the spaces rather than the structure of the mappings. This is addressed in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360119/de-rham-comologies-of-the-n-torus

Answer (score 4):

We cut $T^{3}$ into two parts, each part is homotopic to a torus. One visualize this by considering $T^{3}=T^{2}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}$, and the two parts are $\mathbb{T}^{2}\times I$ respectively, with the $I$ coming out of considering $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ as gluing two intervals together. The intersection of the two parts is again homotopic to the torus. Nowe we have:

$$\rightarrow H^{2}(X)\rightarrow H^{2}(\mathbb{T}^{2}\times I)\oplus H^{2}(\mathbb{T}^{2}\times I)\rightarrow H^{2}(\mathbb{T}^{2}\times I)\rightarrow H^{3}(X)\rightarrow0$$

We know $H^{2}(\mathbb{T}^{2})=\mathbb{R}^{1}$ via induction. So we have

$$H^{0}(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\rightarrow H^{1}(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow H^{2}(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\rightarrow0$$

This gives $H^{2}(X)=\mathbb{R}^{3}$ because last map is an isomorphism and the map $H^{1}(\mathbb{T}^{2}\times I)\rightarrow H^{2}(X)$ has a one dimensional image. Consider a closed one-form $w$ on $\mathbb{T}^{2}$, if we use partition of unity to split it into two parts, then no matter which choice we use we would end up with the same class in $H^{2}(X)$ if one thinks geometrically. This together with the first part gives us $H^{1}(X)=\mathbb{R}^{3}$, $H^{2}(X)=\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: I think you may want to explain exactly how you're cutting the $T^3$ to get the pieces.  Also, it looks like the pieces are not *homeomorphic* to a torus, but rather *homotopy equivalent* to a torus (which is good enough for the rest of your argument to apply.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Why is the intersection not the disjoint union of two tori: $T^2 \times \{pt_1\} \sqcup T^2 \times\{pt_2\}$?

Comment: i didn't how to use partition of unity? can you detail, please? But thanks you for answer.

Comment: Why $H^1(T^2 \times I)\rightarrow H^2(X)$ has a one dimensional image?

Comment: @Eric: At one end they are identified to each other, at the other end they are glued with an intersection. I guess what you said makes sense.

Comment: @user58930: I suggest you to take a look at the Mayer-Vietoris article in wikipedia.

Comment: @user32240: thanks!

Comment: @Eric: Agree with Eric. I calculate the Mayer-Vietoris to be $$0\to 1 \to 2 \to 2 \to H^1T^3 \to 4 \to 4 \to H^2T^3 \to 2 \to 2 \to 1\to 0$$

Comment: @ user 32240: Are you sure you can identify ends? I thought you need ${U,V}$ to be an open cover of $M$.I think maybe you should use Poincare duality to observe that $H^1T^3 \cong H^2T^3$ and then use the fact that a Meyer-Vietoris sequence alternate sums to 0.

Comment: @spitespike: I think Eric's way is better, but I do not have time to recheck the solution right now. I do think Poincare duality is the shorter way to go in calculations.

Answer (score 0):

A linear basis for the vector space $H^\bullet(T^3, \mathbb{R})$ is given by $$ \{1, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \alpha\wedge \beta, \alpha\wedge \gamma, \beta\wedge \gamma, \alpha\wedge\beta\wedge \gamma\}.$$

The product structure on the de Rham cohomology algebra is given by wedge product in the exterior algebra of differential forms. Hopefully this gives some intuition behind the $\binom{n}{k}$ dimensions.